# error when executing update-spsolution

Tags: 2010, powershell

Im trying to update a web part that has been distibuted across our sharepoint intranet and im coming up with an error ive never seen before.  Ive googled but cant find any info.  Can someone help.  The error is below

> Update-SPSolution : The solution cannot be deployed.  The feature
>   '54c38541-0617-4148-8cbc-7ae319ff9cdf' uses the directory
>   "RambollUK.Intranet.SP.MetroLinksViewer_MetroLinksViewer" in the
>   solution. However, it is currently installed in the farm to the
>   directory
>   "RambollUK.Intranet.SP.MetroLinksViewer_RambollUK.Intranet.SP.MetroLinksViewer".
>   Uninstall the existing feature before you install a new version of the
>   solution.
>
> At line:1 char:18+ update-spsolution <<<<  -identity
>   rambolluk.intranet.sp.metrolinksviewer.wsp -literalpath
>   C:\Rambolluk.wsps\RambollUK.Intranet.SP.MetroLinksViewer.wsp
>   -GACDeployment + CategoryInfo: InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...tUpdateSolution:           SPCmdletUpdateSolution)
>   [Update-SPSolution], SPException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletUpdateSolution

Answer (score 1):

It means that your feature is not totally undeployed while updated. What I do is just to uninstall this feature manually using central admin. Delete wsp. If not stsadm and powershell are also good.

Try to check if there is no "**Activate on deploy**" flag is set on to true in visual studio for this feature. Sometimes it causes problems too: on install feature is activated cause of this flag and you try to activate it manually...

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

I suspect namespaces and Feature name has changed in the new version, and during deployment however it creates a clashing due to the Feature ID being still the original one.

Basically, if you renamed the feature between deployments, either un-install original one (if feasible as scenario - as it might crash already in-place web parts if class names have changed in the assembly too) or totally update IDs for Feature, Solution.

Answer (score 0):

If this error occurs it´s because you changed or added anything into the Visual Studio solution or changed namespaces.

Change the Feature ID of all the features of the projekt will make it work!